# MySQL how to get first n groups?

Tags: mysql, group-by

For the follow table TestTable:

```
| Id | Name  | Flags |    
|----|-------|-------|    
| 1  | name1 |   1   |    
| 2  | name2 |   1   |    
| 3  | name3 |   2   |     
| 4  | name4 |   2   |    
| 5  | name5 |   3   |
```

how to group by Flags and return the first 2 groups. That is to say I should return rows:

```
|  1    |  name1  |  1  |    
|  2    |  name2  |  1  |    
|  3    |  name3  |  2  |    
|  4    |  name4  |  2  |
```

I tried this:

```
select * 
from TestTable 
group by Flags 
order by Flags 
limit 0,2
```

However the query returned 2 rows only.

Comment: In your desired result, there's nothing grouped...And you have to specify how the "first" are determined. There's no order in a relational database, unless you specify it.

Comment: order by the grouped key.@fancyPants

Comment: If you have grouped, please show the SQL that grouped it.

Comment: **select * from TestTable group by Flags order by Flags limit 0,2** .What i want is the 4 rows as described however the sql returned 2 rows.@trincot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sub query to take only the first two flags, and join that:

```
select     t.id, t.name, t.flags
from       testtable t
inner join (select   distinct flags
            from     testtable
            order by 1
            limit    2) filter
        on filter.flags = t.flags;
```

See it run on [regtester.com](http://rextester.com/MOXDMX49121)